# Javascript multiplication table specifics

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, multiplication, tabular

I am trying to complete a multiplication table but am running into an issue, this is my code...

```js
function multiTable(number) {
  var table = '';
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    if (i == 1 || number == 2 || number == 3 || number == 4 || number == 5 || number == 6 || number == 7 || number == 8 || number == 9) {
      table += i + " * " + number + " = " + (i * number) + "\n";
    } else if (i = 10) {
      table += i + " * " + number + " = " + (i * number);
    }
  }
  return table;
}
```

When I put it through the tests provided I get ...

> '1 * 5 = 5\n2 * 5 = 10\n3 * 5 = 15\n4 * 5 = 20\n5 * 5 = 25\n6 * 5 = 30\n7 * 5 = 35\n8 * 5 = 40\n9 * 5 = 45\n10 * 5 = 50\n'

I am supposed to get ...

> '1 * 5 = 5\n2 * 5 = 10\n3 * 5 = 15\n4 * 5 = 20\n5 * 5 = 25\n6 * 5 = 30\n7 * 5 = 35\n8 * 5 = 40\n9 * 5 = 45\n10 * 5 = 50'

To save anyone some time the only difference is the very end, the \n after 50.

I don't know if this will help but this is the test:

```js
Test.describe("Basic tests",() => {
  Test.assertEquals(multiTable(5), '1 * 5 = 5\n2 * 5 = 10\n3 * 5 = 15\n4 * 5 = 20\n5 * 5 = 25\n6 * 5 = 30\n7 * 5 = 35\n8 * 5 = 40\n9 * 5 = 45\n10 * 5 = 50');
  })
```

Comment: `i = 10` => `i === 10`

Comment: what alfasin is pointing out is that you are doing an assignment inside your conditional check instead of an equality test. pretty common misteak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the solution here it is

```js
function multiTable(number) {
var table = '';
for(i=1;i<11;i++){
if(i === 10){
table += i+ " * " +number+ " = " +(i*number);
}else{
table += i+ " * " +number+ " = " +(i*number)+ "\n";
}
}
return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function multiTable(number) {
    var table = '';
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; i += 1){ // print 9 times with \n
        table += i + " * " + number + " = " + (i * number) + "\n";
    }
    table += 10 + " * " + number + " = " + (10 * number); // and last line
    return table;
}

console.log(multiTable(5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```